# How to properly convert string to decimal in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string

```
Dim value as String = "10.00"
```

when I try to convert it and store in a decimal variable, I get invalid input exception

```
Dim valueDec as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(value)
```

How can I safely convert it?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I changed '.' to ',' and the problem is gone. Well done VB

Comment: When converting formats, you have to deal with culture-specific settings. If the current culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`) doesn't use these `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator`, `Convert.ToDecimal()` will fail or return a different value than expected. If your input string is `"10.00"`, you can just specify the `InvariantCulture` as the `IFormatProvider` argument of the method: `Dim value As String = "10.00" Dim valueDec As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It clarifies a lot

Comment: Approach in the answer will fail on another machine which has `.` as decimal separator configured

Comment: @bapster: It _is_ well done in VB (respectively .NET), everything is done according to the current windows settings, and where needed one can use the override that takes the InvariantCulture that is guaranteed to remain unchanged forever. One is able to change each thread's translations (CurrentUICulture) and formats (CurrentCulture) individually - they have done a good job!